# Building a multiple/single condition search function in NET.Core (IQueryable or IEnumerable)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ienumerable, iqueryable

I am a beginner in coding in C# (and coding in general, really) and I am trying to create a website to search a SQL Server database for multiple and/or single conditions simultaneously. So far it works like a charm, and very fast, for single conditions but I have so far not been able to render the multiple conditional search. I have scoured both here and there for possible solutions but have come up empty handed either because I couldn't figure out how to implement it yet or because there are methods that doesn't seem to work anymore including multiple where clauses, && and || operators in where clauses and several Microsoft tutorials.

This is my controller:

```cs
var Projektdokumenter = from p in _context.ProjekterDokutypeDokuundertype
    .Include(p => p.Dokumenttype)
    .Include(p => p.Dokuundertype)
    .Include(p => p.Forfatter)
    .Include(p => p.P)
    .Include(p => p.Sprog)
    select p;    
    
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) || (searchProject) != null) 
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                    {
                        return View(Projektdokumenter.Where(p => p.Forfatter.Initialer.Contains(searchString)).ToList());
                    }
                    {
                        if (searchProject.HasValue)
                        {
                            return View(Projektdokumenter.Where(p => p.P.ProjektId.Equals(searchProject)).ToList());
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And this is my view

```html
    <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
        <div>
            <p>
                Forfatter Initialer: <input type="text" name="searchString" value"" />
                Projekt ID: <input type="number" name="searchProject" value"" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a asp-action="Index">Remove Filter</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want the user to enter in "Foo && Bar" and have EFCore interpret that as an AND query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your Controller like below(Assuming your `searchProject` is of type int,and I suggest you to change your method to post):

```
  public IActionResult Index(string searchString,int searchProject)
    {
        var Projektdokumenter = from p in _context.ProjekterDokutypeDokuundertype
        .Include(p => p.Dokumenttype)
        .Include(p => p.Dokuundertype)
        .Include(p => p.Forfatter)
        .Include(p => p.P)
        .Include(p => p.Sprog)
        select p;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) ^ searchProject!= 0)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                var c = Projektdokumenter.Where(p => p.Forfatter.Initialer.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
                return View(c);
            }
            {
                if (searchProject!=0)
                {
                    var d = Projektdokumenter.Where(p => p.P.ProjektId.Equals(searchProject)).ToList();
                    return View(d);
                }
            }
        }
        var e = Projektdokumenter.Where(p => p.Forfatter.Initialer.Contains(searchString) && p.P.ProjektId.Equals(searchProject)).ToList();
        return View(e);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Yinqiu. Although I am now struggling with returning a view without filters, this is definitely a more than appreciated answer to my query.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a model to hold the data. name it SearchResult or something.
2. in the form you can have several searchstrings you can combine to send to the method.
3. make an IQueryable

   ```
    IQueryable<ProjekterDokutypeDokuundertype> result = 
          _context.ProjekterDokutypeDokuundertype
                  .Include(p => p.Dokumenttype)
                  .AsNoTracking();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(dokumentNavn))
    {
        result = result.Where(d => d.DokumentNavn == dokumentNavn);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(forfatterNavn))
    {
        result = result.Where(d => d.Forfatter == forfatterNavn);
    }

    var searchResult = await result.Select(s => new SearchResult { Forfatter = s.Forfatter, DokumentNavn = s.DokumentNavn}).ToListAsync();
   ```

Comment: I will try your solution tomorrow Johan to see the differences between the two. Thanks for the input